How to find the list of jobs that a given program is being used in ? For a AS400 (i-series) system
Suppose I have a program , say PGM1 , I want to find the list of JOBS that are using this program.
Is there any way of getting the list of JOBS using a particular program in AS400 (i-series)?

you could use DSPPGMREF and query the outfile.

WRKACTJOB – Work with Active Jobs and look at the function column
